# Approximating "height" of layout when contains TextView

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface, textview, dimension

I want to use this simple layout for items of list:

[image]

Note the right gray area (which I draw red rectangle on its border in below) must be a *square*:

[image]

So I have to approximate the *height* of layout. It must be simple, but the problem is that the text size of `TextView`s is set by using `sp` unit and height of layout must be set by `dp` unit and I did not found a way for converting `dp` and `sp` in `.xml` file. Also I do not want to create a `CustomView` or change properties of layout at runtime. All things must be done in `.xml` file. How I can approximate height of layout?

Answer (score 0):

See the TextSize is different from TextView's width and height.
So Provide fixed width-height to all views in "dp". Fixed Text-Size in "sp" that fits perfectly inside TextView.
P.S. -> test in a few devices/emulators to verify.